# Closing as duplicate with a different link after it's been reopened shows old link

Tags: support, bug

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332925/type-safety-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion-to-conform-t) was closed as a duplicate of `A`, then reopened. I felt a better duplicate, `B` applied and re-closed it with its link. However, in the duplicate banner, the link for `A` showed up.

When I edited the link to `B` into the duplicate list, it's as if `B` had never been registered.

In the image below, you can see I closed with a link, but had to edit it back into the duplicates list to have it show up in the banner.

[image: This is how it looked to me.]

Looks like a bug to me, but I haven't tried it elsewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't look like the target `A` stuck around; rather, the last addition to the edit list prior to it being re-opened.

Comment: Or that, yeah ^^

Comment: Question is deleted, problem solved :P